# Apache WebSphere Plugin home page

Tags: apache, plugins, websphere, websphere-7

We currently have Apache/ WAS setup and I want the Apache to handle the static content and it is working as expected.

My question:

We have always used www.xxx.com before and WAS used to handle the page, now we want to WEB server to handle the page and route www.xxx.com to www.xxx.com/index.jsp without the user knowing about it.

We want to user to type in www.xxx.xom in the url and get to the WAS through Apache.

Comment: So you want both static Apache content and dynamic WAS content to be served from the root of the server, correct? Or do you only want index.jsp to be served as / ?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you want a reverse proxy for dynamic content of your website. Apache has the [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) that allows you to do that for selective URLs. The [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive allows you to specify what URLs are mapped to which HTTP servers. HTTP headers are modified accordingly that the external information can reach the WAS that is hidden behind your Apache. IIRC, WAS can be configured to be aware of the reverse proxy.

Reverse proxy based on a prefix:

```
ProxyPass /mirror/foo/ http://backend.example.com/
```

Reverse proxy based on a regex:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^(/.*\.gif)$ http://backend.example.com$1
```